# What does the apache ssl error AH02032 mean?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

I'm running "Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Ubuntu)" and I'm looking at my apache error logs and they are filled with the following and I'm having trouble figuring out why this is happening. Can someone explain this error and how I can mitigate this issue?

```
[ssl:error] AH02032: Hostname x.x.x.x provided via SNI and hostname xxx.com provided via HTTP have no compatible SSL setup
```

I'm running 3 virtual hosts with https only.

Comment: Did you run an SSL test tool against your web site?

Comment: yes i did, A- on ssllabs. Appears to only throw some errors on older browsers. Nothing of significance.

Comment: That will be the source of those messages, then. You don't need to do anything that isn't listed on the ssllabs report.

Comment: anyway i can set the error reporting to be less aggressive?  My daily error logs are massive.

Answer (score 3):

[This question is answered here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/134021/what-kind-of-attack-is-prevented-by-apache2s-error-code-ah02032-hostname-prov)

It means there is a mismatch between the target name in the TLS handshake ("provided via SNI") and the target name in the HTTP protocol ("provided via HTTP")

Comment: I saw that but is that the same error because the error message is different. That one says this, "provided via HTTP are different", and the one i'm getting says "no compatible SSL setup". Is this the same thing? I also don't see a remedy to that vulnerability, don't you think someone should post that here?

Comment: Web browsers are responsible, not you. Apache2 has no related vulnerabilities, unless you deliberately misconfigure it.